# working with append to create details

Tags: jquery

i'm trying to create details for each `div` that i have in a list.

just to now, this list can be very long.

so, this is what i have done so far:

examp:

html:

```
<div class='pics'>1</div>
<div class='pics'>2</div>
<div class='pics'>3</div>
<div class='pics'>4</div>
<div class='pics'>5</div>
<div class='pics'>6</div>
```

js:

```
$("div.pics").live("mouseover", function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    var details = "<div id='details' style='border: solid red 1px; width: 300px; height: 300px; position: absolute;'>Detalhes do usuario</div>";
    $this.next().append(details);
});

$("div.pics").live("mouseout", function(){
    if($("#details").length){
        $("#details").remove();
    }
});
```

[**Made a live example**](http://jsfiddle.net/9HBsh/10/)

i have some question now, this is the better way to something like that?

and its not working the append with the last `div` i think its because the `next()`, how can i fix that ?

i'm kinda lost here.

Thanjs!

Comment: adding and removing from the dom is very costly. you should show and hide `div`s instead.

Comment: @Daniel A. White: thanks, what about `.detach()` ?

Comment: jQuery.live? that's like so 2 years ago...you should be using jQuery.delegate

Comment: @DavidKemp jQuery.delegate? that's like so 1 year ago... should be using jQuery.on ;)

Comment: @RichardD thanks, haven't been doing jQuery for a while, but `jQuery.on` makes a lot more sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would create the div on the body and absolutely position it rather than append it to the next div.

You can use [position](http://api.jquery.com/position/) to get the position of the div you are hovering over and use that that to set the `top` and `left` css values for the details div

Something like this http://jsfiddle.net/infernalbadger/9HBsh/12/

```
$("div.pics").live("mouseover", function(){
        var position = $(this).position();
        $('#details').css({top: position.top + 10, left: position.left + 110})
                     .show();        
});

$("div.pics").live("mouseout", function(){
    $('#details').hide();
});
```

Taken Daniels advice into account so the div is hidden first then positioned and shown.

Answer (score 0):

If the details is static information, then better to make them as 'display: none' and show only when user "hover" the div. Because it is too expensive to do what you are doing.